# necessary data rewind wasn't possible

Tags: php, curl, zend-framework, file-upload, webdav

I am trying to upload an uploaded file by the user to a **WebDav** server and I am getting the following error.

> "necessary data rewind wasn't possible"

Here's my code.

```
$config = Zend_Registry::get('settings')->documents;

$upload = new Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http();
$upload->setDestination($config->temp_dir);

if($upload->isValid()){
    $upload->receive();

    foreach($upload->getFileInfo() as $fileInfo){
        if (!isset($fileInfo['name']) || empty($fileInfo['name'])){
            continue;
        }

        $fileName = $fileInfo['name'];
        $filePath = $config->temp_dir . $fileName;
        $fileSize = filesize($filePath);
        $file = fopen($filePath, 'r');

        $remoteUrl = $config->webdav_url;

        $credentials = array(
                'test',
                'test'
        );

        $ch = curl_init($remoteUrl . $fileName);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, implode(':', $credentials));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PUT, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $file);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, $fileSize);
        curl_close($ch);
        fclose($file);
    }
} else { // show the errors}
```

However, when I tried to upload a local file to a WebDav server it's working fine.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of the error is the space in the filename.

Comment: You may want to explain how you fixed the issue (either escaping or encoding the filename, rename it, ...)